# Spring Boot 1.4 : class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

The project without JPA works fine with 1.3, but throws the following exception with 1.4:

```
2016-07-31_19:29:21.758 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at at.oebb.ticketshop.automat.backend.Application.main(Application.java:21) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [ts-automat-0.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [ts-automat-0.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [ts-automat-0.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [ts-automat-0.0.1.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:603) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:443) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:424) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187) ~[spring-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:600) ~[spring-orm-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)`
must be set on the application class and
`spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false` must be set in the application properties/yml.

Comment: It indeed worked for me but can you elaborate on this? What is the problem an how does this fix it?

Answer (score 10):

This happens in  spring boot version 1.4 when you have spring data JPA jars on your dependency and you have no classes in your project annotated with `@entity`.

In order to resolve the issue, you can use jdbc starter instead of jpa in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It indeed worked for me but can you elaborate on this? What is the problem an how does this fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Done it without changing any configurations:

Step 1: Check your absolute path used by ClassPathResource simply by executing `System.out.println(new ClassPathResource("").getFile().getAbsolutePath());`

The output of this snippet will let you know what is the absolute path that ClassPathResource is referring to.

Step 2: Now create your folders which will store the uploaded data, for-example: static/image/ to store images etc. under the output path of the above snippet.

Step 3: Now after creation of folders that you want to refer at exact locations pass in the created folders path as you want to pass before.

For example:

`private String UploadDir = new ClassPathResource("static/image/").getFile().getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work,just update ur SpringBoot to 1.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

the same issues :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6314

Comment: I updated to 1.4.1.RELEASE and still have the problem. Is it working for you?

Comment: you can use spring boot jdbc starter instead of jpa if you don't have classes annotated with @entity

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this while running tests,then this the answer for guys
I am using Spring-boot MVC Tests-2.2.4,i was facing the same error and using
Long story short,i have forgotten to add controller in the webmvc annotation

@WebMvcTest({temp2.class})

This solved the problem