# Jenkins cant create entityManagerFactory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I created the following test for my application:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class exampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mvc;
    private WebClient webClient;

    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
        this.webClient = MockMvcWebClientBuilder.webAppContextSetup(context, springSecurity()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void mvcTest() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void clientTest() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:"+port+"/app/");
        List<DomElement> pageList = loginPage.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        DomElement page = pageList.get(0);
        String text = page.getTextContent();
        assertThat(text).isEqualTo("Please log in");
    }
}
```

When I execute a mvn install on my local machine, everything works just fine. But Jenkins returns the following stacktrace after a build:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence
>   unit root URL
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
>   [spring-boot-test-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
>   [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
>         at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>   [spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160)
>   [surefire-junit4-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
>   [surefire-booter-2.20.1.jar:2.20.1]
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:637)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:459)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:440)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:328)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         ... 44 common frames omitted
>       Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
>         at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:633)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
>         ... 49 common frames omitted

What is wrong with my test that Jenkins can't execute it?

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20799074/error-creating-bean-with-name-entitymanagerfactory?

Comment: Not really because I use the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency and no other dependency for jpa or hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15304

I could reproduce the problem locally when I entered mvn clean install -f ./pom.xml instead of just mvn clean install. In Jenkins, I had set a custom path to the pom-file because the pom file wasnt in the root of the repository. (The path was something like: ./pathToPomFile/pom.xml The solution was to remove the custom path to the pom.xml in Jenkins and move the whole code structure up to the root of the repository.

Comment: this is an epic bro... :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the spring boot version upgrade. I found [this thread](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6314) which is similar to your question and the solution I found is this. Hope this might helpful to you.

> @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =
>   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class) must be set on the application
>   class and spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=false must be set in
>   the application properties/yml.

Comment: This is a new project which doesnt manually configure a factory bean. In the thread the user wilkinsona states: If you want to use Spring Boot's auto-configuration of Hibernate, you should use @EntityScan. If you want to configure things yourself (but I don't understand why you would) then you should probably exclude HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration entirely.
So I use entityScan because I dont want to configure the factory bean myself

Comment: This might be helpful to you. [Just look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686708/spring-boot-1-4-class-path-resource-cannot-be-resolved-to-url-because-it-do/38698101?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: My project has @Entity classes so I can't use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency because my project relies on jpa

Comment: I hope this one should directly helpful to you. He is posting question and answer in the question itself. Have a look. [https://www.jahia.com/home/community/forum/general/jahia-in-english/error-when-trying-to-declare-ent.html](https://www.jahia.com/home/community/forum/general/jahia-in-english/error-when-trying-to-declare-ent.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. I found the solution for my problem and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but re-organizing my repo (like in the "Accepted Answer") was not an option. I ended up using the "Execute shell" build step instead of the build-in Maven step, and my script simply was "cd someDir; mvn clean install".

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `mvn -f ./pom.xml`, you should have a multi-module project (just add at least 1 module to your project)